# PyopenGL collsion detection with 3D cubes

Tags: python, pygame, pyopengl

I was working on making a cube runner game on pyopengl utilising pygame also. However, I have no idea how to code for collision detection. Right now i have a camera and some randomly spawning cubes. The cubes move passed the camera but if a cube is approaching me, it will go straight through. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to do this?

thanks

[btw here's an image of what the game looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxtKd.png)

Comment: Better than an image... some code?